# Не устанавливается расширение AvaloniaUI на Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Версия студии VS 2019 с последними обновлениями.
Попытки установки через маркет vs studio не получилось, установка пакетом тоже.
[image: Ошибка]

**Viev Install Log**

```
05.03.2021 17:17:43 - Ошибка установки: System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi' failed to install
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
---> (Внутреннее исключение #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi' failed to install
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

> Пробовал в ручную установить нечего не вышло...

Comment: А почитать лог? Пишет `Package 'Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi' failed to install`: есть ли такой пакет уже в системе? Если есть - попробовать грохнуть, пусть авалония поставит, если нет -- попробовать сначала поставить пакет руками, глядишь авалония пропустит этот шаг.

Comment: Я даже не знаю где он находиться, подскажите.

Comment: Проблема в том что он не устанавливается и его нету(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Помогло восстановление Visual Studio 2019.**